# Loop through an array for a random string, then remove that string so it can't be chosen again

Tags: javascript, arrays

As above!

I'm trying to produce a knockout competition draw, with an array of teams.

My goal is to:

1. Choose a random team from an array of teams.
2. Remove that team so it can't be chosen again.
3. Loop through until all teams have been chosen.

I have managed numbers 1 and 3 but am struggling to make 2) work within my function. I've tried .push and .splice methods and saving to a variable...

This is what I've got so far...

```
 //create an array of teams
 var teams = ['Aston Villa', 'Burnley', 'Arsenal', 'Liverpool', 'Everton',
              'Man Utd', 'Brighton', 'West Ham', 'Spurs', 'Chelsea', 'Man City', 'Fulham']
 var usedTeams = [];
 var pickedTeam;

 //pick a team randomly from the array
 function pickTeam() {
   for (var i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
     pickedTeam = teams[Math.floor(Math.random() * teams.length)];
     console.log(pickedTeam);
     usedTeams.push(pickedTeam);


   }
 }

//remove that item from the array

//pick another team

//loop until all teams are picked.
```

Comment: How did your attempts - using `splice()` and `slice()` - fail? What went wrong?

Comment: What happens to the picked team? Are you sure that loop in that function is what you want?

Comment: when printing to the console I got 12 results but some repeats

Comment: end goal is to display the teams one at a time either in the console or HTML document, as if to replicate the process of doing a knockout tournament draw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping *in* the function, have the function return a single name, and call the function `team.length` times.

```js
const teams = ['Aston Villa', 'Burnley', 'Arsenal', 'Liverpool', 'Everton','Man Utd', 'Brighton', 'West Ham', 'Spurs', 'Chelsea', 'Man City', 'Fulham'];

function pickTeam() {
  const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * teams.length);
  return teams.splice(rnd, 1);
}

while (teams.length > 0) {
  console.log(pickTeam(), teams);
}
```

If you want to pause between console.logs you can use a setTimeout to loop instead. That you can do *within* the function.

```js
const teams = ['Aston Villa', 'Burnley', 'Arsenal', 'Liverpool', 'Everton', 'Man Utd', 'Brighton', 'West Ham', 'Spurs', 'Chelsea', 'Man City', 'Fulham'];

function pickTeam(arr) {
   
   // If there are elements still in the array
   if (arr.length) {

    // Get a random number
    const rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);

    // Grab that random element from the array
    const el = arr.splice(rnd, 1)[0];
    console.log(el, arr);

    // Wait 1 second before calling the function
    // again with the reduced array
    setTimeout(() => pickTeam(arr), 1000);
  }
}

pickTeam(teams);
```

Comment: This works brilliantly! Is there any way to slow the loop down so it prints one team at a time?

Comment: Yes. Give me a sec and I'll write some explanatory code.

Answer (score 2):

[Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) out that value instead of just taking it.

```
 pickedTeam = teams.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * teams.length), 1)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var teams = ['Aston Villa', 'Burnley', 'Arsenal', 'Liverpool', 'Everton', 'Man Utd', 'Brighton', 'West Ham', 'Spurs', 'Chelsea', 'Man City', 'Fulham'];
 var usedTeams = [];
 var teamsQty = teams.length;
 
for(let i=0; i<teamsQty; i++){
  let pickedTeam;
  pickedTeam = teams[Math.floor(Math.random()*teams.length)];
  usedTeams.push(pickedTeam);
  teams.splice(teams.indexOf(pickedTeam),1);
};

console.log(usedTeams);
```